# Increment through date on week basis

Tags: php, postgresql

I am building a php application using pgsql as its back end.
I would like to increment the date by some amount of date shich should be loaded from my database which have given value as available=1,3,5(implying monday,wednesday,friday of a week).I would like to increment these available values to current date. I am using N format in date() function to represent the values of days in a week as 1 to 7 which is stored in available field in the database

If current date =22-07-2013 which is monday,then i have to increment this to wednesday(available=3) and then to friday(available=5) And then to monday of the next week.

And so on..
but i cant do that..
i am in need of such a code where the value of available may change according to the tuples in that tuple.So i would like to increment the current date based on the value of available.
So please help me to achieve it.

The code I used is attached herewith.Please have a look at it.

```
<?php
$sq         =   "SELECT * FROM $db->db_schema.dept where active='Y' and dept_id=$dept_id";
$result     =   $db->query($sq);
 $ftime=$result[0]['f_time'];
 $ttime=$result[0]['t_time'];
 $a=date('Y-m-d').$ftime;
 $b=date('Y-m-d').$ttime;
 $to_time = strtotime("$b");
$from_time = strtotime("$a");
$minutes= round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
$days=array();
 $days= explode("," , $result[0]['available']);
$result[0]['available'];
 $intl=$result[0]['slot_interval'];
 $slots=$minutes/$intl;
 $dt1 =date("m/d/Y $ftime ");
 $s_mnts=explode(":",$ftime);

 $m= date('N'); 

-- $dt=array();
 $a=$dt1;
 $l=0;
 for($n=1;$n<=3;$n++)
 {

     for($k=$m;$k<=7;$k++)
     { $l=$l+1;
        if(in_array($m,$days))
         {  
         echo "dasdsa"; 
        echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$a +$l days"));
        echo"<br>";
         }
          $m=$m+1;

         if($m==7){$m=1;}
     }
 }
?>
```

where
dept_id -> primary key of the table dept
$db->query($sq); -> query is used to fetch the given values and is defined in another file           named database.php in the program folder.
f_time and t_time -> fields in the table dept which describes the from_time and to_time.f_time is the time from which we have to start increment and t_time is the time to end this increment.

Please inform me whether there is any improvement in the code I have given. .

Comment: We would hate to waste your time, so if you could explain which functions have you tried so far and how did they not work, then we could be sure not to make you retry all teh things you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is something like this:

You say how many days you want to increment. And give an array of availables.

```
<?php
$inicialDate = time(); //Timestamp of the date that you are based on
$tmpDate     = $inicialDate; //Copy values for tmp var
$increment   = 5; //Increment five days
$available   = [1,3,5]; //Days available
/*Ok, now the logic*/
while($increment > 0){
     $tmpDate = strtotime("+1 day", $tmpDate); //Increase tmpdate by one day
     if(in_array(date("N",$tmpDate), $available){ //If this day is one of the availables
          $increment--;
     }
}
$finalDate = date("m/d/Y",$tmpDate);
?>
```

This logic should work, although I don't know how to reproduce it via a SQL Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are after something like

```
UPDATE sometable
    SET some_date_column = some_date_column + ('1 day'::INTERVAL * some_integer_value);
```